# Making a method that is able to recognize the parameter type and call their common methods accordingly

Tags: java, methods, constructor

Below is an example of three methods that have almost the same instructors, excluding the first one (Tile, Primitive, Cube).

Let's assume that for those objects these methods also exist:

```
Tile.set(int a, int b, int c){ ... }
Primitive.set(int a, int b, int c){ ... }
Cube.set(int a, int b, int c){ ... }
```

Now here are 3 different methods that use these methods above:

```
void first(Tile tile, int a, int b, int c){
    tile.set(a,b,c);
}

void second(Primitive tile, int a, int b, int c){
    tile.set(a,b,c);
}

void third(Cube tile, int a, int b, int c){
    tile.set(a,b,c);
}
```

My question is, is it possible to create something like a monster method that recognizes if **tile** (my input) is a **Tile, Primitive** or **Cube**, if we assume that they all have the method **.set**?

Something like this:

```
void monster(Anything tile, int a, int b, int c){
    tile.set(a,b,c);
}
```

// **for lolo** //

Although I know this is wrong, because the method has 3 instructors with the same name, it should only choose 1 from the 3, whatever tile is:

```
void monster(Tile tile, Primitive tile, Cube tile, int a, int b, int c){
    tile.set(a,b,c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use strategy pattern with the use of interfaces.
You can recognize it by `instanceof`

```
if (dog instanceof Dog) System.out.println("dog is an instanceof Dog");
```

---

To be more specific to your question, for example:

```
public interface ISet {

    void set(int a, int b, int c);

}

public class Cube implements ISet {
    @Override
    public void set(int a, int b, int c) {

    }
}

public class Primitive implements ISet {
    @Override
    public void set(int a, int b, int c) {

    }
}


public class Tile implements ISet {
    @Override
    public void set(int a, int b, int c) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ISet set = new Cube(); //just an example. it can be given
    if (set instanceof Cube) {
        System.out.println("instanceof Cube");
    }
}

public class A {
    public void set(ISet set) {
        set.set(0 ,0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. Is it okay if I ask more about it?

So in your example the main method doesn't take any instructors that would be either a Tile, Primitive or a Cube. The part where you wrote ''If set is an instance of Cube, do this...'' is what I want to avoid, because that would mean I would have to create another one if the ISet is a Primitive or a Tile, right?

That looks a bit like recognizing the input (Cube, Tile, Primitive) and separating 3 different methods for them. What I would like to do is the inverse of that I guess. (part2 below)

Comment: I would like my main method to take **any** of the 3 classes (Cube, Primitive, Tile), and run the same **.set** method, whatever the input is, because we're assuming that any of those 3 classes will be able to do the same job, that is run through the **.set** method (I edited my original question and inserted a code at the very bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Inheritance.
Have a base class with the set method.
Make the set method virtual and override it in the Tile Primitive and Cube class
Then Simple call it like:

```
void monster(BaseClass tile, int a, int b, int c)
{
   tile.set(a,b,c)
}
```

This function will accept any class that inherits from BaseClass and will call its overwritten method respectively.

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for the answer. Do you think there's any other way without inheriting? What I mean is that let's assume my Tile, Primitive and Cube classes are very different from each other and don't want to be related to a common class, the .set method is the only one they have in common

Comment: Im not so familiar with Java, but in C# an interface would be your answer.
Give all your classes the same interface:
 `interface Set{ void set(int a,int b, int c) }`
This will require a class to have an implementation of the set method.
So instead of BaseClass tile we can change it to Set:
`void monster(Set tile, int a, int b, int c)`

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface `Shape`:

```
interface Shape {
    void set(int a, int b, int c);
}

class Tile implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void set(int a, int b, int c) {
    }

}

class Cube implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void set(int a, int b, int c) {
    }

}
```

And now you can call it like  :

```
class Test {

   public static void acceptGenericType(Shape shape) {
      shape.set(shape.getA(), shape.getB(), shape.getC());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Shape tile = new Tile();
      acceptGenericType(tile); // calls Tile's set()
   }
}
```

Thereby, you call only the `set()` of *that* particular instance.

Comment: *Edits made based on your comments to another answer.*

Comment: @Hydraxia: Did this answer or any other work for you? If yes do consider accepting one.